# Boost log windows debugger output formatting

Tags: c++, boost, boost-log

As described in [Boost docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/detailed/sink_backends.html#log.detailed.sink_backends.debugger), Boost.log can output messages into windows debug output visible in Visual Studio/DBGView

Boost example shows how to create sink and add it to logging:

```
typedef sinks::synchronous_sink< sinks::debug_output_backend > sink_t;
void init_logging()
{
    boost::shared_ptr< logging::core > core = logging::core::get();
    // Create the sink. The backend requires synchronization in the frontend.
    boost::shared_ptr< sink_t > sink(new sink_t());
    // Set the special filter to the frontend
    // in order to skip the sink when no debugger is available
    sink->set_filter(expr::is_debugger_present());
    core->add_sink(sink);
}
```

But how to set message formatting? For console and file output it looks simple, but not for windows debug output

Comment: There's no difference with other sinks, formatting is configured the same way.

Comment: @AndreySemashev, i tried it before asking and it does not work. debug_output_backend has only default constructor - it does no acceps any 'keywords' like other backends can. But debug_output_backend is derived from basic_formatted_sink_backend, so this should be possible somehow. Do you have any sample?

Comment: Formatting is implemented by the frontend, it is the frontend that accepts the `format` keyword. You can also use `set_formatter` to set up formatting.